# Java Springs: Why does moving XML file inside the package gives me an error

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Java Springs.

I created a package called com.MyFirstSpringPackage inside which there were several Java files, and there is an XML file (outside the package), which were calling the class constructor (wiring the beans) and everything was going fine.

Now i decided to push this XML file inside the package using drag-and-drop using eclipse,and then onwards the program started throwing error:

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Jun 17, 2014 11:03:12 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@15327b79: startup date [Tue Jun 17 11:03:12 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 17, 2014 11:03:12 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [FirstSprings.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [FirstSprings.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [FirstSprings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.MyFirstSpringPackage.MainSpring.main(MainSpring.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [FirstSprings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
```

What is the reason for this error? Why can't i move it inside the package, which is just a folder?

Comment: Can you show the code where `FirstSprings.xml` is referenced please?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 did you refer to the xml file using the package name after moving it like com/MyFirstSpringPackage/FirstSprings.xml ?

Comment: @Jens:  `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("FirstSprings.xml");`

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Try to use `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/FirstSprings.xml")`

Comment: @Jens: Arvind's method works, only using slash gives me error.

Comment: @Arvind: Why don't you put an answer for everyone else's benefit, so that i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the package name to refer the xml file like:

```
String xmlFile = "com/MyFirstSpringPackage/FirstSprings.xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the resolution is by mentioning the spring xml file path by using forward slashes `/` as below:

```
Resource r = new ClassPathResource("com/ioc/container/resources/springioc.xml");
```

Works fine.